# Applying IP of a router in another router as a DNS server

Tags: routing, dns

There are 2 router let it be X and Y. For X I have registered on ddns and got a hostname for the router and applied that for remote management. In Y router I have applied the fixed public IP of router X as a DNS server. When I am getting connected to router Y I am able to download(though at a very low speed) but web pages are not opeaning.

Comment: You need to give us more detail. For instance, what router models and configurations?

Comment: both are Netgear JNR1010v2 routers.

Comment: Those are consumer-grade devices, and questions about those are off-topic, here. You should ask on [su].

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you set X as the DNS of Y? The DNS is only used to resolve the hostname<->ip pair.

Is there a particular reason why you want X to be the DNS of Y or it is the same for you? Because if it is the same, you could set X as the gateway of Y and use a public DNS for Y; for instance the Google DNSs (`8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`) or Open Dns (`208.67.222.222` or `208.67.220.220`)

Comment: If i set X's gateway in Y will it redirect the whole traffic?

Comment: You can set the IP of X as the gateway of Y and then the whole traffic will go through X because at that point all the packets that don't belong to the Y private subnet will be redirected to the ateway (in this example X). Anyway it is not really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: actually I'm trying to put malicious DNS server in Y router so that it gets redirected to my malacious page. And a question to your above answer that I should put public IP of router X in router Y and public IP gets changing.How to solve that?